# Vote feature implementation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Hello I get an error saying `Could not find overload for != that accepts the supplied documents` and don't know what to change.  I am stuck for a very long time. I am trying to implement a vote feature in a collection view.  If the user taps the button it adds one vote to parse and shows it on the label. Is my method wrong? Below is the code for Collection view cell the highlighted code is where the error is.

```
import UIKit
import ParseUI
import Parse

var votes = [PFObject]()


class NewCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var parseObject = PFObject(className: "Posts")
    @IBOutlet weak var postsImageView: PFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var votesLabel:UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        postsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
         print("Passing11")

    }


    @IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {
```

> ```
>         if (parseObject != nil)
> ```

```
            {
                if let votes = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
                    parseObject!.setObject(votes + 1, forKey: "votes")
                    parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
                    votesLabel?.text = "\(votes + 1) votes"
                    print("Passing22")
                }
                else
                {
                    parseObject!.setObject(1, forKey: "votes")
                    parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
                    votesLabel?.text = "1 votes"
                     print("Passing33")
                }
            }}}
```

And I also have an error "use of unresolved identifier parse objects"

```
          if (parseObject != nil)
{

    if let votes = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes) votes"
    }
    else
    {
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "0 votes"
    }
}
return cell}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiler error will appear only if your parseObject is of type PFObject and not PFObject?.
From what I can see through your code:

```
var parseObject = PFObject(className: "Posts")
```

The above line states that your parseObject will be of type PFObject and not optional. It will be optional only if your initializer is failable.
So if parseObject is not optional, then there is no need for nil check.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It is also wrong to force-unwrap something that is not an Optional, so `parseObject!` is also wrong.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. however I also found a huge problem. When tapped like, the label does count up and looks nothing wrong. But in parse dashboard, it creates a empty object and puts the votes in there. It does not enter the number of votes in the correct object.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific. Parse Dashboard ?